# What is invalid about css selector using :is()

Tags: css, css-selectors

so I started trying to use `:is()` pseudo selector for a project I'm working on. the queries I was writing though do no seem to be working.

```
:is(.column-1,.column-3,.column-5,.column-7) .gallery__item:nth-child(1)
```

I ran each query through `document.querySelector`, and it came back with error telling me that it's an invalid selector. tried to refactor my selectors but I haven't had much luck. any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: missing star `*` in front of `:is` is the issue?

Comment: In chrome you need to enable `Experimental Web Platform features` in `chrome://flags/` for it to work, So you can experiment with it, After all it's just a compacting syntax Your selector can be rewritten as `.column-1 .gallery__item:nth-child(1), .column-3 .gallery__item:nth-child(1), .column-5 .gallery__item:nth-child(1), .column-7 .gallery__item:nth-child(1)`

Comment: @Sebastian Brosch: The * is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, CSS selector `:is()` isn't supported by most browsers, see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ais())...